# Curl Redirect Issue C++

Tags: c++, curl

I want to use Curl to download and parse data from this website:

http://xetra.com/xetra/dispatch/en/xetraCSV/navigation/xetra/100_market_structure_instruments/100_instruments/100_all_tradable_instruments/

I have used my Curl code on different websites before and it works without issue but this site is different in that it returns a redirect response with an actual link containing the data.

I enabled this setting:

```
    curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE));
```

but I get caught in an infinite loop of redirects filling the log file.

To avoid this, I then parsed the initial HTTP response to get the redirect location, and attempt to download using that link. However, Curl tells me the headers and body are empty (CURLE_GOT_NOTHING) and throws. When I visit using a browser I can see the data loading so I know that there is something there, Curl just doesn't seem to be able to see it.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,
pma07pg

Many thanks to Captain Giraffe for this answer!

If you have have a redirect link and need to store the cookies then add these options:

```
    curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS , 5); // Stop redirecting ad infinitum
    curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");
```

Comment: Maybe try setting CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS to 1 and CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS appropriately and see if that resolves the issue

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Sadly this didn't resolve the issue. Curl complains about hitting max number of redirects and then stops running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the JSESSIONID cookie to not get redirected.

Add the cookie you receive on the first request (302 Found)  to your headers, repeat the request et viola.

Sample dealing with [libcurl Cookies here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/cookie_interface.html)